# Loading large data with pandas directly from hdfs with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am fetching data directly from database, there are about 5 - 12 million of data. When i tried to convert this into pandas dataframe to do profiling . it keeps crashing due to the high volume.

for an example

```
df1 = spark.sql("select * from database.table")
sample = df1.toPandas() ## this is where it wont execute
```

I have read that some have adviced to use dask, and chunksize . but this are reading as csv then convert to a dataframe wherelse i am fetching directly from a database. is there a efficient way that i could load this data as pandas dataframe at a very short time ?

Comment: If you want to load it in Pandas, why won't you read it in pandas directly?

Comment: if i were to load to pandas directly , it will still take a long time to load. is there any way we could load pandas dataframe faster with high volume of data?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. And hence it is taking a long time to convert to a pandas dataframe as well. you should work in spark or move to dask. [Docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_sql)

Comment: I am working with spark too but i am trying to utilize pandas-profiling library to check the quality of the data.  hence i am trying to use convert from spark to pandas then to pandas profiling , is there a method to use pandas-profiling directly from spark ?

Comment: You can try using Grouped Map/Grouped Aggregate pandas_udf and apply the profiling from inside I guess? I don't know how profiling works

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with using the function `toPandas()` is that will load all the data to the Driver. Is pretty like using an old school `collect()`.

If you are trying to use the profiling of the library in Pandas I would recommend the usage of the [Koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas) and check if it suits you. Koalas is a library that convert pandas functions in Apache Spark code in the background. So maybe it will help you.